# Printing a list array which uses threads to a text area in java

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, printing

I am having problems storing and printing a list array which uses threads. I want to store the list of threads in a list array and print them to a text area where they can be sorted by a user. The code below is my array class and transaction class.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * @author B00533474
 */
public class Array {
    ArrayList<Transaction> transactionList = new ArrayList<Transaction>();

    // Variables
    private final Transaction nextTransaction;
    public static int inInt2 = TranAcc.inInt2;
    public static int inInt3 = TranAcc.inInt3;
    public static String inInt1 = TranAcc.inInt1;

    //public static void main(String[] args){
    public Array(){
    nextTransaction = new Transaction(inInt1, inInt2, inInt3, 2000);
    transactionList.add(nextTransaction);
    transactionList.get(3);

    }

    /*public static void main(String[] args){
        Array ar = new Array();
        ar.add(nextTransaction);
    }
     * 
     */
}
```

The variables inInt1 etc are from another class called TranAcc which is the main GUI of my project.

```
package bankassig;

/**
 *
 * @author B00533474
 */
public class Transaction {
    String type;
    int amount;
    int wkNum;
    int balance;

    public Transaction(String ty, int am, int wk, int bal)
    {
        type = ty;
        amount = am;
        wkNum = wk;
        balance = bal;
    }


}
```

My problem is actually implementing/using the list area, I was going to add an action listener to a button on a gui which would call the list area and print the transactions in a text are but I was unsure of the code to write for this ( I know about the action listener just not calling the list array).

Any help would be much appreciated and if I need to provide anymore code I would be happy to do so.

How do I implement the list array and use it to print out the values of the variables which I used?

Comment: My main question is how do I implement the list array and use it to print out the values of the variables which I used? `inInt1` etc

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite the inherited (from java.lang.Object) toString() method in your Transaction class. In your toString() method, you can put together a String with your variable data in any format that makes sense to a user, and return it. You can then iterate through all the Transactions in your Array class's list, call the toString() method, and put it in your GUI. Something like:

```
for (Transaction trans : yourArrayObj)
{
    yourTextArea.append(trans.toString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I think this is correct! The only problem now is whenever i try to access the `transactionList` list array. It gives me an error saying that it cannot reference a non static variables from a static context. So I tried to make it static but this gave me an error in the array class saying: _cannot assign a value to final variable nextTransaction_ . Would you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Create an Array class like you have in your code example above. Then add a main method and create a new Array object in that main method.

Comment: Okay thank you, would that just be something like `Array arrayObject = new Array();` then would I need something to add to it to use that variable? @Eric Hydrick

Comment: Yes, in your main method, Array arrayObject = new Array() and you can start adding whatever you want to it. By the way, why is nextTransaction final?